# SSRS Parameters Displaying incorrectly

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

Basically, I have a datetime parameter, after picking a date with the calendar widget, the date will display correctly (12/1/2010 or 1-DEC-2010). If the parameter tab refreshes in any way, either from report processing or changing another of the parameters, the date flips the month and day (1-DEC-2010 becomes 12-Jan-2010, or 12/1/2010 becomes 1/12/2010).

I'm utilizing the SSRS plugin for C# (Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms.ReportViewer).

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seem like an other problem I had with localization and culture.

For me, french culture : 01/12/2010 means 1 december 2010

In english culture : 01/12/2010 means 12 january 2010.

You may take a look at youre Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Comment: This was the issue. Not sure why it was reverting the date format/culture to that, all the servers involved are set to en-US. Thanks for the insight, I didn't realize that the month/day are reversed in some countries.